# Project doesn't work after adding maven dependency (xdocreport)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xdocreport

I've been worked on a resource to convert DOCX files into PDF ones using xdocreport, and I add maven dependency of docx/pdf conversion, my project just stop working.

This is the dependency that stops all:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>    
    <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.docx.xwpf</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Even I just create some class if main method and try to run it, I just prints 'terminated' on Eclipse console top bar. When I try to debug this same simple class, I got this message:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.launching 4 120 2017-06-21 08:42:47.825
>
> !MESSAGE Cannot connect to VM !STACK 0 java.net.SocketException:
> Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking

Does anywork know how to solve this problem, I don't know where or what is causing this bug?

**More info**

[POM file](https://gist.github.com/carlosspohr/74c2a6c6ba4610a26aa5dfb4756f3bdc)

[ConversionTest](https://gist.github.com/carlosspohr/918f50e7a4b79a2206e6198316727723)

JVM Version: 1.8.121 and also tested with 1.7.80

Eclipse Neon.3 - Windows 10 x64

Tips: I just create a project in Intellij and copy paste pom dependencies and ConversionTest and works perfectly ..

Comment: Have you tried to run maven from comman line?

Comment: Maven dependencies are resolved correctly, and running it from CLI or through Run as maven-install is OK too. I modified my code to point to docx that doesn't exists, then I run maven expecting some exception, but it not happened: https://gist.github.com/carlosspohr/f72f01538f7aa7dd6462f3ebfd771767